# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException in Xamarin iOS C#

Tags: c#, ios, mysql, xamarin

I have searched on stackoverflow but cannot find any solution.
I use a mysql server from a hosting.
I am developing a product for my graduation. 
we will use a mysql server, a raspberry pi and an iOS device.
raspberry can connect mysql server via Java code and its working fine. But I cannot connect my Xamarin solution to mysql server.
what can I do ?

If anyone can help me, I will be very happy. :)

I use same code of example of library as a connection string: https://components.xamarin.com/view/mysql-plugin

```
// imports:
using UIKit;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;

// CONNECTION PART OF THE CODE 
try{
   MySqlConnection sqlconn;
   String connsqlstring = "Server=myip;Port=3306;database=mydbname;User Id=myusername;Password=mypassword;charset=utf8";
   sqlconn = new MySqlConnection(connsqlstring);
   sqlconn.Open(); // EXCEPTION IS HERE !!!!
}catch(MySqlException e){. //SOME CODES  }
```

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the
>   specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Could
>   not resolve host '**.**.***.***'   at System.Net.Dns.Error_11001
>   (System.String hostName) [0x00000] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.2/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/Dns.cs:308
>   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostByAddressFromString (System.String address,
>   System.Boolean parse) [0x00034] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.2/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/Dns.cs:377
>   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry (System.Net.IPAddress address)
>   [0x0000e] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.2/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/Dns.cs:404
>   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry (System.String hostNameOrAddress)
>   [0x0004b] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.2/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/Dns.cs:394
>   at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.GetHostEntry (System.String
>   hostname) [0x0000c] in <5e4982151d314701bcfe1f0a397fe0db>:0    at
>   MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.CreateStream
>   (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings,
>   System.Boolean unix) [0x00008] in <5e4982151d314701bcfe1f0a397fe0db>:0
>   at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetTcpStream
>   (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
>   [0x00000] in <5e4982151d314701bcfe1f0a397fe0db>:0    at
>   MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream
>   (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
>   [0x0000b] in <5e4982151d314701bcfe1f0a397fe0db>:0    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open () [0x00007] in
>   <5e4982151d314701bcfe1f0a397fe0db>:0     --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open ()
>   [0x00027] in <5e4982151d314701bcfe1f0a397fe0db>:0    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open () [0x0000b] in
>   <5e4982151d314701bcfe1f0a397fe0db>:0    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create
>   (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
>   [0x00036] in <5e4982151d314701bcfe1f0a397fe0db>:0    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection ()
>   [0x00000] in <5e4982151d314701bcfe1f0a397fe0db>:0    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection () [0x00083] in
>   <5e4982151d314701bcfe1f0a397fe0db>:0    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver () [0x00042] in
>   <5e4982151d314701bcfe1f0a397fe0db>:0    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection () [0x0001c] in
>   <5e4982151d314701bcfe1f0a397fe0db>:0    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open () [0x000ad] in
>   <5e4982151d314701bcfe1f0a397fe0db>:0    at
>   MySQLDemo2.ViewController.LoginButton_TouchUpInside (UIKit.UIButton
>   sender) [0x00063] in
>   /Users/magoya/Projects/MySQLDemo2/MySQLDemo2/ViewController.cs:36

Comment: Is your Raspberry connected to the network?

Comment: yes it is connected to MySQL via java code. It's working fine. But in c#, I got this problem

Comment: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." seems like a pretty obvious error message.  Are you running on a emulator or actual device?  Have you verified connectivity to your server?  Are you using localhost/loopback, or the ACTUAL IP of the server machine?

Comment: iOS simulator of Xcode is connected to Visual Studio. I'm running on this.
Verified because, my raspberry pi and my MacBook can connect to MySQL with Java code. 
Not local host. I bought a mysql server from a company. I think if there is a problem about mysql server, I could not connect it from another device but I can.